# Submitting form with jQuery .ajax() giving me a null?

Tags: php, jquery, cordova

Here is my javascript. I am trying to have jQuery send my sign in form data over to my PHP file. I then tell it to grab the data from the php file and display it. But all that is coming back is "null". If I request another value such as bio, it can display it. But it cant display data sent from my form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img").click(function() {
            var data = $('form#signin').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url:'signin.php',
                type:'POST',
                data: data,
                success:function(data) {
                    $("p.test").html(data);
                    $.getJSON("signin.php", function(data) {
                        localStorage.email = data[0];

                    });
                },
                error:function(data) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my PHP

```
<?php

$email = $_POST["email"];

$profile = array($email, "Karl", "Clement", "Gangsta Love!", "bio bio bio bio bio bio bio     bio bio bio bio bio bio bio bio bio bio bio", "Ottawa",     "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/1459354642/IMG_1560_normal.jpg");

header('Content-Type:text/json');
echo json_encode($profile);

?>
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The proper content-type for json is `application/json`

Comment: Please show us the complete form.

Comment: Why do you have the two-step process calling the same PHP page twice? Can't you have it return the appropriate information from the first call?

Comment: application/json, doesnt change anything since I get still get data from my PHP file. If I call data[1]; it displays "Karl". But for some reason, if I try to pass $email back to jquery, it says null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getJSON sends a GET-request, but you try to access a POST-variable.(to be exactly you don't send any variables via $.getJSON )

The $.ajax()-request with a datatype set to 'json' should be sufficient:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img").click(function() {
            var data = $('form#signin').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url:'signin.php',
                type:'POST',
                data: data,
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data) {

                        localStorage.email = data[0];

                },
                error:function(data) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am sending data with .ajax() and retrieving data with .getJSON

Comment: You try to access data[0] in the callback of getJSON, where signin.php will not return anything for $_POST['email'] because $_POST is empty. The call of getJSON is needless in your code, use only the $.ajax() - request with a datatype set to 'json'

Comment: Correct. Why is it empty? How could I fix it?

Comment: Could you post an example of what you mean? Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's great, avoid redundancy. Is my PHP ok though?

Comment: You could enclose the whole statement into a condition `if(isset($_POST["email"])){}` . Apart from that fact(and the already mentioned wrong Content-Type) it looks fine.

Comment: Thanks Dr. Molle, I made all the changes you suggested and voila. I believe it was the second call of my signin.php that was causing an error. Anyway, works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

have you tested to make sure you php is sending data back? Since you're in phonegap you need to reference the php on your server, also make sure you've white listed the external hosts in your plist.

In xcode, in your phoneGap.plist file you'll see external hosts, add a new entry there, the key doesn't matter, but the value set to *, this will allow all external domains.

Then in your php just echo something "hello world" and console.log that message in your ajax.

If that works then you know your able to access your php, so the next step is to pass your variables over to is, start by just echoing

```
json_encode($_POST['email']);
```

if that works the next step is to send back the whole request -

```
echo json_encode($profile);
```

Just console log the data result before assigning any localStorage, if the data result comes back as expected then assign vars using the index like you are currently, BUT do just like dr.mobile said, you don't need that extra request, you already have the data.

Comment: I was able to pass through from my php array "Karl" which is at position 1 in my array. The only value that doesnt pass is the $email value.

Comment: and you're sure that your input name is email in the form?

Comment: Yup. It's weird...the place that seems to break is that the data from my form isnt POSTing so that I cant use it from PHP $_POST()

Comment: hmm try something real quick - do a console log of your serialized form, the data you're sending to the php, see how it's formatting things... that may give a clue as to what the problem is...

Comment: email=sdglkjsdgn&password=dghdh